# Куда ставить ударения в этих сложных числах?

Tags: орфоэпия, числительные

Куда ставить ударения в сложных числах типа `стосорокаоднолетие`. Меня особенно интересуют слова с приставками `одно`, `сорока`, и `сто`. Первые части таких слов обычно происходят от родительных словоформ - `двадцати́пяти́ле́тие` – и поэтому ясно куда ставить ударения, но в случаях `одно` и `сто` точно не так.

Самое главное, в этих словах произносятся ли какие-нибудь `о` как `/о/`, т.е. будет `/сталетие/` или `/столетие/`? Зависит ли произношение от присутствия других чисел, т.е. произносится `сто` по-разному в словах `столетний` и `стопятидесятилетний`?

Answer (score 1):

Главное ударение всегда идёт на `лет` с любыми числами.

В `сорока` - ударение на `а`.

Произносится `/сталетие/`. Другие тоже с `а`.

На этом сайте есть ударения и фонетические транскрипции практически всех слов (в том числе и чисел): [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/столетний](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97813/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd-------).

Comment: Имею ввиду, что в очень длинных словах может быть `/ста|сто/` (но не в `столетие`). Другие буквы лучше произносить как `/a/`.